# Python hashlib - Update and Digest for list comprehension

Tags: python, list, syntax, list-comprehension, hashlib

I would like to do a list comprehension that hashes elements from 2 lists. I assumed it would look like this:

```
hashes = [hashlib.md5().update(a + b).digest() for a, b in zip(f,l)]
```

(assume elements in `f` and `l` are encoded properly)

I'm unable to do this and I need to incorporate the use of a helper function

```
def update_digest(s):
    h = hashlib.md5()
    h.update(s)
    return h.digest()
```

It seems the `update()` method does not return an instance of the object to use for sequential calls. I would've like to do something analogous to `'BOB  '.strip().lower()`

Clearly, my only motivation is using it in a list comprehension.

Is there a way to do this?

If not, why doesn't `update()` return an instance of the object? I feel like there's something I don't know about hashing that prohibits it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update method does not return anything, it just updates the object on which it's called. It's just how it's designed.

But you can omit the update and feed the data you want to hash directly to the constructor, so you don't need the helper function:

```
hashlib.md5("foobar").digest()
```

Your call could look like this:

```
hashes = [hashlib.md5(a+b).digest() for a, b in zip(f,l)]
```

Comment: For future reference, in Python 3, `a` and `b` must be `ASCII` encoded explicitly in order for this to work.